# Confused with a sufficient (and necessary?) condition (KKT?) for (local or global?) optimality in a nonconvex optimization problem

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let an optimization problem reads

\begin{alignat}{2}
\text{(P1)} \quad \text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}} \quad & f(x) \\
\text{subject to }\quad &  g_m(x)  \leq 0 \quad m=1,\ldots,M,
\end{alignat}
where $f(x)$ is a convex and differentiable function. However, $\{g_m(x)\}$ are nonconvex functions but closed (and proper if needed for the optimality condition?).
ADD: Assume $g_m$ to be an indicator function but to a nonconvex set.

Forming a Lagrangian of $\text{(P1)}$, we have
\begin{align}
L(x, \{\lambda_m\}) = f(x) + \sum_{m=1}^M \lambda_m \ g_m(x).
\end{align}

I am confused with the optimality conditions for a nonconvex optimization problem ($\text{P1}$).

**Questions**:

- Are [KKT conditions](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F16/lectures/kkt.pdf) **sufficient (and necessary?) conditions** for local? (or global?) optimality? If not, then what are the correct ones to characterize the optimality?
- Suppose $x^\star$ and $\{\lambda_m^\star\}$ are (local? or global?) optimal values, then does the following saddle point hold in nonconvex optimization as well?
  $$L(x^\star, \{\lambda_m\}) \leq L(x^\star, \{\lambda_m^\star\}) \leq L(x, \{\lambda_m^\star\})$$

***KKT Conditions***:

1. *Stationarity condition*: $0 \in \partial L\left( x, \{\lambda_m\}\right) {\color{red}{\Rightarrow 0 \in \nabla f(x) + \sum_{m=1}^M \lambda_m^{\star} \ \partial g_m(x) ?}} $, where $\{\lambda_m^\star \geq 0\}$ are optimal Lagrange multipliers that maximizes the Lagrangian.
2. *Complementary slackness*: $\lambda_m \ g_m(x) = 0$ for all $m=1,\ldots,M$
3. *Primal feasibility*: $g_m(x) \leq 0$ for all $m=1,\ldots,M$
4. *Dual feasibility*: $\lambda_m \geq 0$ for all $m=1,\ldots,M$

Comment: If the functions $g_m$ were assumed to be differentiable, then a standard result would tell us that the KKT conditions are necessary (assuming that a constraint qualification is satisfied).

Comment: My intuition is that the subdifferential is only a useful substitute for the gradient for convex functions. So if the functions $g_m$ are nonconvex, I would guess that the KKT conditions you’ve written are not necessarily satisfied for an optimal point $x^\star$.

Comment: @littleO I see. If $g_m$ is an indicator function to a nonconvex set, then would $g_m$ be a convex or nonconvex? It is nonconvex, isn't it? But the subgradient of an indicator function is a normal cone, isn't it?

Comment: The indicator function of a nonconvex set is a nonconvex function.